# How can I check whether image is renderd on page or not?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to check image rendering on page level. Problem is when image url is loaded but that image is not present on that url, page shows a block with red cross(x) at top. I want to check whether image is in page or not.

---

I only wants to know "Can we check whether image is loaded or not on page level?"

Comment: bind onerror event on image

Answer (score 0):

When you request a resource that the server cannot deliver, the server responds with a 404 status. The 404 status is what you need to check for. If it returned 200, or some other codes, you can be fairly sure the image loaded fine.

Also, the page isn't showing that block with the red cross, your browser is.

I cannot help any further as you've not specified what you're working with, what server type, what programming/application language, etc.

Comment: I only wants to know "Can we check whether image is loaded or not on page level?"